# Why is Standard Deviation the square of difference of an obsevation from the mean?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am learning statistics, and have some basic yet core questions on SD:

> s = sample size
>
> n = total number of observations
>
> xi = ith observation
>
> μ = arithmetic mean of all observations
>
> σ = the usual definition of SD, i.e. `((1/(n-1))*sum([(xi-μ)**2 for xi in s])**(1/2)` in Python lingo
>
> f = frequency of an observation value

1. I do understand that `(1/n)*sum([xi-μ for xi in s])` would be useless (= 0), but would not `(1/n)*sum([abs(xi-μ) for xi in s])` have been a measure of variation?
2. Why stop at power of 1 or 2? Would `((1/(n-1))*sum([abs((xi-μ)**3) for xi in s])**(1/3)` or `((1/(n-1))*sum([(xi-μ)**4 for xi in s])**(1/4)` and so on have made any sense?
3. My notion of squaring is that it 'amplifies' the measure of variation from the arithmetic mean while the simple absolute difference is somewhat a linear scale notionally. Would it not amplify it even more if I cubed it (and made absolute value of course) or quad it?
4. I do agree computationally cubes and quads would have been more expensive. But with the same argument, the absolute values would have been less expensive... So why squares?
5. Why is the Normal Distribution like it is, i.e. `f = (1/(σ*math.sqrt(2*pi)))*e**((-1/2)*((xi-μ)/σ))`?
6. What impact would it have on the normal distribution formula above if I calculated SD as described in (1) and (2) above?
7. Is it only a matter of our 'getting used to the squares', it could well have been linear, cubed or quad, and we would have trained our minds likewise?

(I may not have been 100% accurate in my number of opening and closing brackets above, but you will get the idea.)

Comment: 1) Raising 7 questions in the same post is too much.
2) This topic does not belong in "Stack overflow". Post it in "Mathematics" instead.
3) Please try to format the text better, as this looks like a mess.

Comment: The 7 questions are all related so I put them together. On the mess, its a markdown table, looks quite okay when I am in edit/preview mode. Will try to make it plain text. Also, I realized this question might be more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com, shall do that. I am not sure if I should delete this question here.

Comment: Yes, stats is probably the best place for it. You can probably delete this one after you've re-posted it :)

Comment: I got a brilliant answer, so keeping this question here. :)

Comment: Just a quick comment while reading the excellent answer by Arshiya above. One amazing thing about the Central Limit Theorem is that you can make an inference about sample mean that it always follow normal distribution, no matter how the sample is distributed (under some conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you are looking for an index of dispersion, you actually don't *have* to use the standard deviation. You can indeed report *mean absolute deviation*, the summary statistic you suggested. You merely need to be aware of how each summary statistic behaves, for example the SD assigns more weight to outlying variables. You should also consider how each one can be interpreted. For example, with a normal distribution, we know how much of the distribution lies between ±2SD from the mean. For some discussion of mean absolute deviation (and other measures of average absolute deviation, such as the median average deviation) and their uses see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation).

Beyond its use as a measure of spread though, SD is related to variance and this is related to some of the other reasons it's popular, because the variance has some nice mathematical properties. A mathematician or statistician would be able to provide a more informed answer here, but squared difference is a smooth function and is differentiable everywhere, allowing one to analytically identify a minimum, which helps when fitting functions to data using least squares estimation. For more detail and for a comparison with least absolute deviations see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations). Another major area where variance shines is that it can be easily decomposed and summed, which is useful for example in ANOVA and regression models generally. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) for a discussion.

As to your questions about raising to higher powers, they actually do have uses in statistics! In general, the mean (which is related to average absolute mean), the variance (related to standard deviation), skewness (related to the third power) and kurtosis (related to the fourth power) are all related to the **[moments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISaVvSO_3Sg&t=842s)** of a distribution. Taking differences raised to those powers and standardizing them provides useful information about the shape of a distribution. The video I linked provides some easy intuition.

For some other answers and a larger discussion of why SD is so popular, See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151/339128).

Regarding the relationship of sigma and the normal distribution, sigma is simply a parameter that *stretches* the standard normal distribution, just like the mean *changes its location*. This is simply a result of the way the standard normal distribution (a normal distribution with mean=0 and SD=variance=1) is mathematically defined, and note that all normal distributions can be derived from the standard normal distribution. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602593/985958) illustrates this. Now, you can parameterize a normal distribution [in other ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Alternative_parameterizations) as well, but I believe you do need to provide sigma, whether using the SD or precisions. I don't think you can even parametrize a normal distribution using just the mean and the mean absolute difference. Now, a deeper question is *why* normal distributions are so incredibly useful in representing widely different phenomena and crop up everywhere. I think this is [related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49212/importance-of-normal-distribution) to the Central Limit Theorem, but I do not understand the [proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Remarks) of the theorem well enough to comment further.

Comment: This is SO helpful! Thank you for taking the time out! I will go through the links you have pasted so that I develop a better 'intuition' of this field.

And I also did have a taste of the Central Limit Theorem, and was lost why it is so! For now, I have accepted it at its face value.

Comment: You're very welcome! The CLT has a pretty interesting history and some proofs which I linked, though as I said I'm not familiar with them myself!